# Vectors in Pre-Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

The following question was asked in my assignment of Functional Analysis and I was not able to solve this.

> Question: Show that if $x_1,...,x_n$ are any vectors in a pre-hilbert space then $(E,||.||)$ , then $\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n =+1, -1} || \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i x_i ||^2 =\sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i||^2$.

Attempt: I tried to prove it for n=2 only. RHS equals $||x_1||^2 + ||x_2||^2$. LHS equals$\frac{1}{4} ||x_1+x_2||^2 + ||-x_1-x_2||^2$ . But I am not able to simplify more of LHS to reach to RHS.

Can you please help me with the case n=2.

Thanks!

Comment: Whar happened to $\|x_1-x_2\|^{2}$ and $\|x_2-x_1\|^{2}$? Do you know the parllelogram identity?

Comment: I think you've slightly misunderstood the intended meaning of the notation. The $\epsilon_i$s don't all need to be the same (i.e. it's not the case that they all have to be $1$, or they all have to be $-1$). There should be $2^n$ terms in that sum, not just $2$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS equals $$\frac{1}{4}\left( \lVert x_1+x_2 \rVert^2 + \lVert x_1-x_2 \rVert^2 + \lVert -x_1+x_2 \rVert^2 + \lVert -x_1-x_2 \rVert^2\right)= \frac{1}{2}\left(\lVert x_1+x_2 \rVert^2 + \lVert x_1-x_2 \rVert^2 \right)$$ Now use the parallelogram identity for norms defined by an inner product.